# What do the numbers 2 & 3 mean (duplet/tuplet/finger indication?) in this first bar of a song?

Tags: sheet-music, violin, tuplet

I was looking for a simple anime song piece where I encounter this piece whose first bar does not make sense to me (I uploaded the first bar picture ).

Especially what is meant by 2 and 3 at the top of the first two notes? Is it tuplet or finger indication? [image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The 2 is a fingering notation; the 3 is over the middle and in a different font and size, so I can tell that the 3 is the indication to play a triplet (and the measure only adds up for a triplet). So that 3 doesn't necessarily mean to finger the first A with the 3rd finger, though you may wish to.

**The notation means:**

- **Play the F♯ with your 2nd finger**
- **Play those three eighth notes as eighth note triplets**

*(This is not super clear upon viewing. Good question!)*

Comment: I thought so about 3 being a triplet, otherwise measure does not add up just like you have said. I was confused because of 2 as I did not notice the front difference.

Answer (score 6):

The 2 is a fingering indication.

The 3 (which is in italics and a larger font) is indicating that the three notes are a triplet - so the first three notes take one beat.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well, like others said: the font and positioning (and beaming) make clear that the first is a fingering indication and the second is a triplet indication, but...

If I were playing this, I'd rather use a "1" on the first note, then a "3" where the triplet "3" is written.  That way you can play a "4" on the B and don't need to change strings for two notes (what's that last A supposed to be?  Another "4", making for a lonely "B" on the A string, or "0" making for a two note phrase on the A string?).

As a note aside: it would appear that this is sort of a partitura (since "Violin" is marked and other instruments apparently follow below) which makes it a bit unusual that fingering indications are printed at all.

But a bass figure this clearly ain't.

Answer (score 0):

Those just look like fingering indications, but yes that rhythm only makes sense if it is triplets. Sometimes they go un-notated.